# Recommended books to stay sharp

Tags: calculus, reference-request

Alight dudes, so I'm starting a CS/Math major in March ( well hopefully at least ) and I'm scared I might be a little rusty to start ( I'm 22 so not directly after school ), now my intention is to prepare myself for the rigorous ordeal ahead by being on top of things and sharpening my math skills and intuition, so I'd like some of you guys to help me out by suggesting some books ( preferably available online ) with a LOT of exercises to help me out, anything that includes an introduction to calculus I & II, linear algebra and some basic integration techniques would be good.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You might like Erdman's [Exercises and Problems in Calculus](https://profs.info.uaic.ro/%7Efliacob/An1/2017-2018/Resurse%20pentru%20seminarii/RPS10/John%20M%20Erdman_Exercises%20and%20Problems%20in%20Calculus.pdf). It contains a lot more than you will need, but starts from the beginning and seems quite exhaustive. It also contains answers to the odd-numbered exercises.

As for linear algebra, I would recommend Sergei Treil's [Linear Algebra Done Wrong](https://sites.google.com/a/brown.edu/sergei-treil-homepage/linear-algebra-done-wrong). It covers a nice selection of topics, is quite well written and has lots of good exercises.

Comment: LADW was not written for be beginners. Same for LADR, Hoffman, etc. Gilbert Strang's book should be used as an intro to the subject.

Comment: @xbh: This is true, but the OP asked for sources of exercises, not textbooks. Were they working through the text themselves, I would perhaps recommend something a little easier, probably one of Strang's texts (incidentally, you say "Strang's book", but Strang has written more than one book, so this is vague). I trust that the OP is able to judge for themselves whether LADW is a decent complement to their course, or if not, that they are willing to ask their lecturer for guidance.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my problem. If the OP did ask for exercises, then a lot of classic problem books could be recommended. P.S.  I was referring to the text that G. S. used in his MIT linear algebra course.

Comment: @xbh: I think that's still vague, as he has almost certainly used more than one book over the course of his career teaching that course. There is [Halmos' classic problem book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Algebra-Problem-Dolciani-Mathematical-Expositions/dp/0883853221), but I find that problem texts of that nature are unsuitable to use alongside an ordinary lecture course, as the problem text will require you to work quite diligently through the book, while the lectures march on at an independent pace. Just my experience.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I was referring the LA course posted on MIT open course ware with videos. See [18.06](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/index.htm). The text is "intro to linear algebra".

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend Apostol's Calculus I & II. These can be found online for free at http://www.matematica.net/portal/e-books/Apostol%20-%20CALCULUS%20-%20VOLUME%201%20-%20One-Variable%20Calculus,%20with%20an%20Introduction%20to%20Linear%20Algebra.pdf and http://www.matematica.net/portal/e-books/Apostol%20-%20CALCULUS%20-%20VOLUME%202%20-%20Multi%20Variable%20Calculus%20and%20Linear%20Algebra,%20with%20Applications%20to%20Differential%20Equations%20and%20Probability.pdf, respectively.

The second volume covers linear algebra, so you should be good, but it can get pretty pedantic. Another good lin alg book is **Linear Algebra Done Wrong** which can be found online for free at https://sites.google.com/a/brown.edu/sergei-treil-homepage/linear-algebra-done-wrong.

Comment: LADW is not suitable for beginners. Gilbert Strang's book and online courses might be a good introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but to start your leveling up I recommend to read

[A mathematical bridge: an intuitive journey in higher mathematics (second edition)](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/6985)